# Unlock bootloader of Samsung Tab A 9.7 SM-T555

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-tab, internal-sd, bootloader-lock

Here it comes a long intro of what I want to achieve and what I tried. You can jump to the end for the actual questions.

The internal storage of my Tab is full, so I bought an SD card. Unfortunately, Samsung does not allow me to format it as internal storage. So I tried to do it via `adb shell`, but it did not work. I checked whether I could instruct Whatsapp to store media files on the external SD card, but did not find a way. I also moved Whatsapp to the SD card, but it continued to store media files on the internal storage. So I decided to root the Tab in order to move the whatsapp folder to the SD card and create a soft link to it. I decided to use Odin and CF Auto Root for that, since it seems the simplest and less intrusive way to achieve what I want. But then I saw the bootloader should be unlocked. I did not find a way to check the status of the bootloader (tried the dialing trick and going into "downloading" mod). And I do not have an "OEM unlocking" option under "Developer options". I tried doing the trick of changing the date to make the OEM-unlock option visible, but it did not work. Then I read some people say that if I do not have that option, my bootloader should be unlocked. But I do not know if I can trust that information. I also saw it might be possible to unlock the bootloader with Superboot, but it seems to be a very old tool, so I cannot find a working link to download it and, moreover, I do not know if I can trust it to work with my Tab.

Can someone please confirm that my bootloader should indeed be unlocked if I do not have the OEM-unlocking option visible? Or could someone tell me how can I unlock my bootloader or ultimately achieve what I want to do (i.e., fool Whatsapp into storing media files on the external sd card)? 
Thanks!

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3747535

Comment: Thanks @alecxs From what I read in that thread, does it mean the only way to get the OEM-unlocking option visible is waiting 7 days w/o rebooting the Tab? Does this works even if I do not have a SIM card in the tablet?

Comment: add Samsung or Google account and WiFi, no SIM required

Comment: Will try, thanks

Comment: My SM-T555 still don't have an option to unlock the bootloader. Waited long time, with wifi network enabled.